# How to show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)!2^{2n+3}}=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)!2^{2n+3}}=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

Comment: As the lhs is written, the sum is $\frac{1}{4} \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)$

Comment: This is a [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)! 2^{2n+3}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)! n! 2^{3n+3}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(n+1)8^{n+1}}$$
but since (from the OGF for [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), for instance):
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x}\right)$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(n+1)! 2^{2n+3}} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)}.$$